# How can I add Images for each user to Ubuntu 12.04 Logon Screen?

Tags: 12.04, users, login-screen

I am not talking about having unique backgrounds on the login screen.

What I am looking for is a icon image besides each user name on the logon screen. This was something that was possible in ubuntu 10.04 (I think it was called "Human" or something similar).

I've searched the forums high and low with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: @gman please don't add greetings or signatures.

Comment: Perhaps look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289260/upgrade-to-13-04-user-picture-shows-up-on-lightdm-can-i-change-it/354028#354028) for getting a picture associated with accounts in the `lightdm`/Unity greeter.

Answer (score 3):

Go to System Settings > User accounts > click the logo beside each user in the right section and browse for desired photo or select one of the existing

Installing another Display Manager (GDM 3) does what you want.

Execute `sudo apt-get install gdm` then **restart** your machine.

If at anytime you needed to roll-back:

`run sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` and select **lightdm** to go back to the original one.

Comment: This works when the screen is locked. But I'm looking for an image in the initial logon screen, when the system is initially started and provides a list of users to select from. [Unfortunately, I cannot post images]

Comment: I think this is not supported in LightDM display manager and you will need to install another Display manager ; gdm 3 perhaps.

Comment: @RudyF Answer edited for steps to install an alternate Display Manager

Comment: @RudyF Glad to help, don't forget to mark as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

In Dash type User Accounts **---->**

[image]

Click beside the name to choose a picture or browse for one .

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys, but, unfortunately, this does not show in the initial logon screen ... the one that shows up when the system initially starts. That's where I need the image.

Comment: @AvatarParto The other answer barely mentioned this, so in this case it's ok. nux: Just remember, while it's ok here (since you've added a bit more information) try not to post duplicate answers.